# GCC Debug Flags SCons

Tags: c++, c, build, scons, flags

I've been using qmake up till now and it passed the correct flags for GCC to generate debug information when compiling without me ever having to worry about passing the correct flags. Now I have to use SCons due to the needs of the project and I've not yet still gotten used to it. **How do I pass debug flags to GCC using SCons so that GCC can generate debug information for GDB?** (By the way, I already tried `'-g'`, but it didn't work.)

Thanks in advance to anyone who replies!

Comment: Which version of SCons are you using? Did you go through this documentation -> http://www.scons.org/doc/1.0.1/HTML/scons-user/x1392.html?

Comment: How did you already try passing '-g' to GCC?

Answer (score 3):

To pass flags to the compiler you can set one of the following [SCons Construction Variables](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#app-variables).

**CPPFLAGS**

User-specified C preprocessor options

**CFLAGS**

General options that are passed to the C compiler (C only; not C++).

**CCFLAGS**

General options that are passed to the C and C++ compilers

**CXXFLAGS**

General options that are passed to the C++ compiler

For example, if you are only using C++, you can do the following:

```
env = Environment()
env.Append(CXXFLAGS='-g')
env.Program(target='yourTarget', source='yourSource.cc')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add options to the SCons command line using `AddOption`. For example, your SConstruct could look like this:

```
AddOption('--dbg', action='append_const', dest='cflags', const='-g')
AddOption('--opt', action='append_const', dest='cflags', const='-O2')

env = Environment()
env.MergeFlags(GetOption('cflags'))

SConscript('SConscript', exports={'env':env})
```

Your SConscript wouldn't change:

```
Import('env')
env.Program('foo.c')
```

You control the compilation with command-line parameters to scons:

```
$ scons -Q
gcc -o foo.o -c foo.c
gcc -o foo foo.o
$ scons -Q --dbg
gcc -o foo.o -c -g foo.c
gcc -o foo foo.o
$ scons -Q --opt
gcc -o foo.o -c -O2 foo.c
gcc -o foo foo.o
```

Reference:

- http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user/apd.html
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html